# Need Boolean converter Struts2 for Yes, No, Blank Values

Tags: struts2, boolean

I need to save data based on value selected on UI form element

```
<s:select key="invoice.productSold" list="${productSold}" />
```

productSold dropdown list of values ''(blank), 'Yes', 'No'.

My BooleanConverter

```
public class BooleanConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {

@Override
/*From form*/
public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
        String value = values[0];
        if (value == "") {
            System.out.println("null");
                return null;
        }
        if ("No".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || "0".equals(value)) {
                return "false";
        } else if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || "1".equals(value)) {
                return "true";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}

@Override
public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
        Boolean value = (Boolean) o;
        return String.valueOf(value);
}

}

public class Invoice{

Boolean productSold;
<getter>
<setter>
}
```

#### Issues

1. My form dropdown am selecting to 'Yes' and updating; after update my dropdown is not showing "Yes".  It displays blank.
2. ConvertFromString method returning "true" when Selecting "Yes" on form and ConverToString method returning "false".

#### Action class

---

```
public UpdateAction extends ActionSupport{
protected List<String> productSold;
public List<String> getProductSold() {
    List<String> myOptions= new ArrayList<String>();
       myOptions.add("");
       myOptions.add("Yes");
       myOptions.add("No");

    return myOptions;
}
```

---

Comment: make productSold of type List<Object> and now all values blank "Yes" and "No"  will be accomodated.

Comment: I don't see, why you need a `TypeConverter`, please post your action with `list="${productSold}"`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Added action class.

Comment: @Rizstien I have it is List<String>

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a custom boolean converter, use Struts2 internationalization feature for getting 'nice' texts for booleans.
Put `true = Yes` and `false = No` to your messages properties and then use `listValue` attribute of `<s:select>` tag to call `getText` method to get messages for `true` and `false`.

```
<s:select key="invoice.productSold" list="productSold" listValue="%{getText(top)}"/>
```

BTW you do not need to use any "special" notations inside `list` attribute to get value from the value stack.

BTW no.2: You do not need this `productSold` method inside your action, instead you can define your yes/no list right in JSP using OGNL notation for lists `{...}`.

```
<s:select key="invoice.productSold" list='{"", true, false}' listValue="%{getText(top)}"/>
```

Comment: and why does it has `${productSold}` instead of `%{productSold}` ? Use straight Struts2 tags for a nice living...

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Thanks, missed that, just copy-pasted from OP question.

Comment: Yeah I guessed that... my considerations was directed to OP btw :)

Comment: I forgot to +1, nice answer

Comment: @AleksandrM This is a form and I have to choose 'Yes' 'No' '' <blank> to submit/update details. And I cannot use Struts2 tags; since project has JSP tagslibs.

Comment: @user1769790: You CAN use Struts2 tags and seems like you already use `<s:select>` tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM In project I have it as <v:select> and a taglib.  I have similar "", "Yes" "No" dropdowns; and my bad

Comment: @user1769790: Even if you are using some other taglibs you still can use Struts2 tags, so use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public UpdateAction extends ActionSupport{
    protected Map<Object, String> productSold;
    public Map<Object, String> getProductSold() {
        Map<Object, String> myOptions= new HashMap<>();
           myOptions.put(null, "");
           myOptions.put(Boolean.TRUE, "Yes");
           myOptions.put(Boolean.FALSE, "No");
        return myOptions;
}
```

And in JSP:

```
<s:select key="invoice.productSold" listKey="productSold.key"
          listValue="productSold.value"/>
```

Comment: Tried this and Am not getting the dropdown list to choose Yes, No on form