# How to preserve NULL state in a Boolean sending an empty String from JSP to Action

Tags: jsp, struts2, boolean, type-conversion, interceptorstack

I have a criterion in a search page that is a `boolean`.
Since it is not mandatory, I can't use a checkbox, because I may want to skip it;

JSP

```
<s:select list = '#{ "":"Make your choice...", true:"FOO", false:"BAR" }'
          name = "myBooleanCriterion" />
```

Action

```
private Boolean myBooleanCriterion;

/* Getter and Setter */
```

We know that `boolean` defaults to `false`, while `Boolean` defaults to `null`, then the first time the page is rendered, it is ok (*"Make your choice"* is displayed).

After the POST, however, Struts instantiates the `Boolean` property (defaulting it to `false`) even when it finds `""` as value, so when I come back to the JSP, the value is preselected to `false` (*"BAR"*).

How can I instruct Struts to not create an instance of that variable if the value is `""`, leaving it to its original, `null` state ? Do I need to create a Converter, or to specify something in the `.properties` file ? <sub>(I've basically the same code as in [example .2 from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14476427/1654265))</sub>

I'm using (a slightly custom) `paramsPrepareParamsStack` Interceptor Stack.

I feel like if I'm missing something stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `XWorkBasicConverter` converts `boolean`-s exactly the same way it converts `Boolean`-s, by using `Boolean.valueOf()` method, the empty string or `null` will be converted to `false`.

In order to have `null` after submit you need to create a custom converter for `Boolean` or don't submit this parameter at all. (E.g. Change `name` attribute with javascript if selected value is `""`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was already setting `disabled` on the field when empty before posting it (but changing the `name` is nice too), I've asked this question to know if there is a "right" way to do this that doesn't involve creating a converter. Appearently, there is not :/