# In struts, How can I receive null for Boolean?

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

e.g.

```
class TestAction
{
    @Getter @Setter
    Boolean enabled;// null for both
}
```

HTML

```
<input type='radio' name="enabled" value='true'> enabled
<input type='radio' name="enabled" value='false'> disabled
<input type='radio' name="enabled" value='null'> both
<!-- value=null will convert to false -->
```

How can I pass null for `Boolean` ?

**UPDATE**

Answer is impossible. I use another way below.

Comment: Have you try empty value for both ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255612/how-to-preserve-null-state-in-a-boolean-sending-an-empty-string-from-jsp-to-acti

Comment: `Boolean.valueOf("") == false`, The only way is custom the value.

Comment: See also [Struts2 s:if test for non-null value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22248699/573032) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My way to around this.

```
@Data // Generate all setter and getter.
public class UserSearchCondition implements ISearchCondition
{
    private String enabled = null;

    public Boolean isEnabled()
    {
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(enabled) || enabled.toLowerCase().equals("null"))
            return null;
        return Boolean.valueOf(enabled);
    }
}
```